# IE9 adding extra height to lines with display:inline-block and overflow-x:hidden;

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

Look at the example HTML code below, it works nicely with all browsers apart from IE9 (haven't tested earlier IE versions).

Comparing the page shown by IE9 and Chrome for instance, you will see that IE9 adds extra height to the lines. This happens when display:inline-block and overflow-x:hidden; are present. The issue also happens only if  is present (but I need that for other features, this is just a minimal example showing the issue). Removing either  or overflow-x:hidden; then also IE9 displays more compact lines (same height as Chrome).

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<style>  span { display: inline-block; width: 50px; overflow-x: hidden; } </style>

<div><span>1st</span><span>first</span></div>
<div><span>2nd</span><span>second</span></div>
<div><span>3rd</span><span>third</span></div>
<div><span>4th</span><span>fourth</span></div>
<div><span>5th</span><span>fifth</span></div>
<div><span>6th</span><span>sixth</span></div>
<div><span>7th</span><span>seventh</span></div>
<div><span>8th</span><span>eight</span></div>
<div><span>9th</span><span>ninth</span></div>
```

Link to page with the content above: http://pgn4web.devio.us/pgn4web/IE9bug.html
Try opening the link with IE9 and Chrome! You'll see lines spaced with more blank space with IE9. If then you open the IE9 debugger pressing F12 and you disable the overflow-x:hidden; attribute, you will see the list getting more compact on IE; if you do the same with the Chrome debugger, the display does not change.

Any suggestion how to avoid the extra height added by IE9 (by keeping  and overflow-x:hidden;)?

Thanks

Comment: you should use a **reset styling** prior to do cross browser web development. [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) is a good way to start.

Comment: @balexandre: you might be right, but still does not explain the behaviour of IE9, the more I think about it, the more it looks like a bug...

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem numerous times when trying to add `text-overflow` to an `a` element. I needed the element to have a width in order to control the overflow, so I added `display: inline-block`, but IE9 would therefore position the element higher than where it should be (and is on all other browsers.

Long story short, the problem was the `vertical-align` which I have set to `bottom` and the problem was fixed. If your case is similar to mine, this could be the solution to your problem.

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does IE9 behave when you add a full, real doctype? Browsers do check what comes after the word "Doctype"... this is why you could get browsers to go into Quirks or Almost-Standards Modes with a doctype containing the word PUBLIC but then not having the referrer URL afterwards (and why when the WHATWG tried to reduce the doctype to as small as possible, found that the bare minimum necessary was <!doctype html>... yes, on some forums we all thought we could get away with silly things like <!doctype foo> and be awesome but we were disappointed when one browser or another went batshit on us :( which is too bad, I would love a <!doctype foo>).

Second, I would be horribly uncomfortable setting an normally-inline element to some kind of block setting and then playing with overflow without setting things like:

- a font size, esp. it's a good idea to set a % font size on  the body first, and a line-height
- a font-size, line-height and/or height on the element you've changed.
- vertical-align. This element has been set to display: inline-block after all.

I wish I could get my virtualBox running so I could see for myself in IE9, but what does its developer toolbar tell you about the span? Is it getting a different height? A different line-height? What happens when you set a background-color on the span? What happens when you change the vertical-alignment on the span (inline-block elements are sensitive to vertical-align and no, I haven't found browsers to agree on what the default if I don't explicitly set it myself).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<style>  
div
{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
span 
{ 
    display: block; 
    width: 50px; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    float:left;
} 
</style>

<div><span>1st</span><span>first</span></div>
<div><span>2nd</span><span>second</span></div>
<div><span>3rd</span><span>third</span></div>
<div><span>4th</span><span>fourth</span></div>

<div><span>5th</span><span>fifth</span></div>
<div><span>6th</span><span>sixth</span></div>
<div><span>7th</span><span>seventh</span></div>
<div><span>8th</span><span>eight</span></div>
<div><span>9th</span><span>ninth</span></div>
```

Comment: float: left puts the span in block context, so you can even leave the display: block part out. But we don't know why the OP wanted the spans to be inline-block rather than block (but, maybe block/float does the job for the OP in this case though).

Answer (score 0):

I encournted the same problem today. Here's my work around for you:

```
  div {
    line-height: 0;
  }
  span {
    line-height: 1.1; /* set back to normal */
  }
```

or

```
div {
  height: 20px;
}

span {
  height: 100%;
}
```

or

use display:block; height: 100%;

Still trying find the roort cause.